# "authorized dealer for apple" or "authorized dealer to apple" or "authorized dealer of apple"

Tags: prepositions, usage

Which of the following is correct?

> authorized dealer for apple

or

> authorized dealer to apple

or

> authorized dealer of apple

Comment: Apple themselves use the term "Apple Authorised Resellers" and "Apple Authorised Service Providers". The key idea is that Apple are responsible for the authorization, and hence we keep Apple and Authorised together. Your term leaves open the possibility (albeit, not a very likely possibility) of some other authority having authorised the dealer.

Comment: @djna - Almost, except that they use the NAmE spelling _Authori**z**ed._

Comment: @P.E.Dant. Really??? On this site it is **Apple Authorised Resellers** . https://locate.apple.com/eg/en/ Maybe they locali**s**e it?

Comment: @JavaLatte Well duh P.E. Dant, of course they must do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you want a term for a business that has been authorized to by Apple to sell their products to customers.

[for](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) can have this meaning:  **being employed by or representing a company, country, etc.**. This sounds perfect for a business that has been authroized to represent Apple (and sell their products).

[to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to) does not have any suitable meanings. To me, it sounds like they are authorised to sell things **to** Apple.

[of](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of) can have this meaning: **about; relating to**. This doesn't really work very well, though it would work as

> authorized dealer of Apple products.

Answer (score 4):

They are all correct, depending on what you want to say, additional context is needed

> authorized dealer for Apple
>   authorized dealer to Apple

both can mean you are an authorised dealer to Apple Inc for supplies Apple may need.

> authorized dealer for Apple *(products)*
>   authorized dealer of Apple *(products)*

both can mean you are an authorised seller of Apple products to the general public.